# Sentry module integrated with Magento

Tags: log

Found this one: https://github.com/amg-dev/magento-amg-sentry-extension
Anyone else having other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Damn it, I should have a look into the world.

I implemented today on the mage hackathon an extension for [Hackathon_Logger](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Logger): [Hackathon_LoggerSentry](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/LoggerSentry)

Works on the first view, if you try it and find bugs, tell me, I'll resolve them :)

Comment: Thanks Fabian, look good. I am testing to move couple of clients to Sentry for logging to see how things work out.

Answer (score 2):

I can't vouch for this other than I found it trying to research this same question, but in case anyone else is also looking and wants a more up-to-date answer, there's this: https://github.com/justbetter/magento2-sentry